# Node.js transformation from NAD83 to WGS84

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, wgs84, srid, node-js

I've used the excellent [npm shapefile library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/shapefile) to import Canadian electoral districts into MongoDB. Here's a sample file: http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/geott/electoral/2011/fed308.2011.zip

Is anyone familiar with a node.js tool that would allow me to do this? I'm familiar with Django and the GIS tools provided by Geodjango, but am new to GIS development in the Node.js ecosystem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NAD83 / WGS84 are about 1 m apart. Does it matter for this data?

Comment: How about [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)?

Comment: mkennedy, it would unfortunately. 

MikeT, I just came across proj4js but am having trouble finding a code sample. Do you know how I could just that to convert a geoJSON object?